# how to depend on two fields to make a dropdown depend list django ajax

Tags: django, ajax

i'm trying to make an app for insert locations for a specific purpose , these my models :

```
class City(models.Model):
   city = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Area(models.Model):
   city = models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   area = models.CharField(max_length=40)


class Street(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.street


class Nearest(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    street = models.ForeignKey(Street,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    nearest_place = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

my views.py

```
def load_city_area_street(request):
    city_id = request.GET.get('city')    
    city = City.objects.get(id=city_id)    
    area = Area.objects.filter(city=city_id).all()
    area_id = request.GET.get('area')
    area_name = Area.objects.get(id=area_id)
    street = Street.objects.filter(area=area_name)

    return render(request,'locations/dropdown.html',{'city':city,'area':area,'street':street})
```

my template

```js
    $('#id_city').change(function(){
        const url = $('#post-form').attr("data-city-area-street-url");
        const cityId = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            data:{
                'city':cityId

            },
            success:function(data){
                $('#id_area').html(data);
                
            }
        })

    })
```

```html
<form id="post-form" method="POST" data-city-area-street-url="{% url 'locations:load_city_area_street' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            {{form.as_p}}
        </div>
     </div>                                                

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">save</button>         
</form>
```

but it works only for the area field , i need to make a change for several fields for example

```
$('#id_city #id_area #id_street').change(function()
```

but it doesnt work !
isnt there a better way to achieve that please? thank you

Answer (score 0):

repeat the template jQuery code for area and street with different url and different function in views.py.

Comment: i did it , but it doesnt success in some cases

Comment: what kinda cases? try to run the server in incognito mode whenever you change the script file of the project. that might help too

Comment: sometimes happen two or more city and area have the same street name , it cause the error